# facebook messenger bot template

Tags: bots, facebook-messenger

I am trying to implement a Facebook bot for my application. I see on the web many great examples, like the one of Skyscanner and Uber. However, reading the official documentation, there are few available templates. For instance, I don't find the template to show a path on the map, with the start and end locations.
Are these templates available but not officially documented, or they are just a test for selected companies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding what Uber will offer in the Facebook Messenger app ([see here](https://newsroom.uber.com/messengerlaunch/)) it's definitely not open to the public yet. It's a really deep integration in the app and not only related to send message to a bot.

What you can do however is what Skyscanner do (or [CNN](https://m.me/cnn), or [20minutes](https://m.me/20minutes)) is a great integration with the [Facebook Messenger bot API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform). You will only be able to send a reply to a user who send you a message. That won't go deeper for now.